# WMIC with XCopy: Copy file from Remote System to Shared Location

Tags: xcopy, wmi

Today I found one issue where, I would like your help...
Situation: I want to copy my remote file (which is not shared directly) to other system (which is shared)
so, basically it's like Remote Location D Drive file to copy to some shared location

For that I have used WMIC command which is not working. However direct XCOPY with normal drive or folder transfer it's working well.

Working Code:

```
C:\Users\bmshah>WMIC /NODE:"Server1" /USER:"domain\bmshah" /PASSWORD:"xxxxxxx" PROCESS CALL CREATE "XCOPY /Y \"D:\7.txt\" \"D:\11.txt*\""
```

Not Working Code:

```
C:\Users\bmshah>WMIC /NODE:"Server1" /USER:"domain\bmshah" /PASSWORD:"xxxxxxx" PROCESS CALL CREATE "XCOPY /Y \"D:\7.txt\" \"\\Server2\SharedFolder\11.txt*\""
```

If you observed, the only difference is last destination part. I also tried following options:
1) escape sequence using \" at start & end
2) give full permission on that shared folder to guest & all & anonymous logon
3) tried to use <> instead of double quotes 
4) tried with ' (single quote)

But nothing works here...
Any idea will really appreciate...

Regards,
Brijesh Shah